# Mean of combined sublists with different lengths

Tags: python, numpy

I have a seemingly simple issue. Consider this list:

```
a = [[12.0, 5.0, 63.0], [0.1, 2.0, 7.1, 3.0, 2.3, 5.0, 8.4]]
```

I want to find the mean (using `numpy`) of all the elements in its sublists combined. In this case the result should be:

```
10.79
```

obtained as:

```
np.mean([12.0, 5.0, 63.0, 0.1, 2.0, 7.1, 3.0, 2.3, 5.0, 8.4])
```

The solution I've found is to [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/1391441) first and then obtain the mean, as:

```
np.mean([item for sublist in a for item in sublist])
```

but this seems unnecessarily complicated. I would've assumed that `numpy.mean()` could handle this case without the need to modify the list first. I tried using the argument `axis` to no avail.

Am I missing some functionality here?

Comment: How is that complicated? It's literally doing exactly what you specified in your problem statement, nothing more. It's also literally the simplest list comprehension you can write over a nested list.

Comment: "Complicated" in the sense that I expected `numpy` to automatically handle such a case via some argument. Not "complicated" as in "the code is hard to read/comprehend".

Comment: If you use the numpy `array` data structures I'm pretty sure it automatically flattens the data for you without needing to pass an argument.

Comment: So just cast to `np.array`

Comment: @machineyearning: that won't work because the lists are different sizes.  OP needs to flatten first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your nesting is only one level deep, the concatenation can be done very easily using `np.hstack`.  This will treat the inner lists as vectors, then concatenate them end-to-end as a 1D numpy array.  You can then take the mean of the resulting array.  So this will do what you want:

```
>>> np.hstack(a).mean()
10.79
```

Or equivalently (but more verbose in my opinion):

```
>>> np.mean(np.hstack(a))
10.79
```

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't though of using `np.hstack()`. Thank you!

Comment: But look at what `hstack` does: `np.concatenate([atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup],axis=0)`.  It does a list comprehension on your list.  Actually that isn't needed here.  This will do: `np.mean(np.concatenate(a))`.  The key is understanding what this does compared to `np.array(a)`.  Most cases when you apply a `numpy` function to a list, it first turns that list into an array (or maybe a list of arrays).